# Differences in language parsing speed when indexing a forum (HTML code)?

Tags: html, performance, indexing, processing-efficiency

I was wondering if some programming languages are faster then others if it comes to processing and parsing a HTML page.

My intention is to scan over thousands of HTML forum pages and processing the code looking for specific `<div>` tags and content.

If there are no real differences what language would you recommend me for such a task?

Comment: As far as I know, there shouldn't be any significant difference between any **modern** languages. Assuming that your Internet connection speed remains constant, the rate at which a program pulls from the Internet should also remain the same.

Comment: Thought there may be some differences between executable function implementations and available packages for parsing. With many thousands of pages some small differences can make hours.Will of course try to implement on my side as effective as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends.
You definitely should take a look at programming languages like node.js, python or php and figure out what works best for you.

I personally would recommend using something like node.js because it's a non-blocking programming language.

Comment: Depends on what? Like I mentioned in my previous comment I want to know if there are some efficiency differences in the implementation of the different languages. Also if there packages available how efficient they may be depending on the implementation in the language.
My next step would be looking for **efficient** ways to implement it in that language.

Personally I prefer C and Python but because of job and university I have plenty of experience in Java and JS (and multiple others), thus I don't really care about the language itself.